# Scroll gets stuck

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my ReactJS app, I have a state that is active only when the page is scrolled to the top.
I implemented it this way:

```
const [isFirstPosition, setIsFirstPosition] = useState(true)

const changePositionStatus = () => {
    if (window.scrollY === 0) {
        setIsFirstPosition(true)
    } else {
        setIsFirstPosition(false)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', changePositionStatus);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', changePositionStatus);
    };
}, [])
```

At the same time, when scrolling the page, sometimes the wheel does not respond, then it works again. Usually you have to move the mouse to do this.

I assumed that when scrolling in any position except the top, I constantly execute:

```
setIsFirstPosition(false)
```

And it too expensive for app.
I rewrote this function:

```
const changePositionStatus = () => {
    if (window.scrollY === 0) {
        setIsFirstPosition(true)
    } else if (isFirstPosition) {
        setIsFirstPosition(false)
    }
}
```

But it did not help. What am I doing wrong?